# Mixing R1C1 and A1 notation

Tags: vba, excel

Struggling through applying a normal excel formula into R1C1 format so I can loop the formula in VBA. The question is how can I refer to columns in other sheets using R1C1 notation. So in the following formula:

```
ell.Offset(0, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(R[]C[-2])>0,(R[]C[-2])*VLOOKUP([R[]C[1]),Core!A:C,3,FALSE)/_
VLOOKUP(R[]C[-1],Core!A:C,3,FALSE),R[]C[4])"
```

How do I get Core!A:C into R1C1 format? I know you can't mix the two formats but i'm afraid i don't know the syntax for this! Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

```
Sub Expo_dos_Formulas()

'===============================================================================
Sheets("Data_Sheet").Activate

For Each cell In Range("G5:G500")
    If cell <> "Error" Then
        cell.Offset(0, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(R[]C[-2])>0,_
(R[]C[-2])*VLOOKUP([R[]C[1]),Core!RC1:RC3,3,FALSE)/VLOOKUP(R[]C[-1],_
Core!RC1:RC3,3,FALSE),R[]C[4])"
    End If
Next
'===============================================================================

End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In place of `A:C` put `C1:C3`:

```
ell.Offset(0, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(RC[-2])>0,(RC[-2])*VLOOKUP(RC[1],Core!C1:C3,3,FALSE)/_
VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Core!C1:C3,3,FALSE),RC[4])"
```

When using R1C1:

1. the `[]` will denote a relative non absolute reference.  For example `RC[-1]` refers to the cells directly to the left.
2. If absolute references are wanted then do not use the `[]` and it will refer to the row/column number. For example `R[1]C3` will return the row directly under the one being referenced but in column C.  If the referenced cell is `A3` then it would return `$C4`.
3. If full column or full row are wanted then discard the `R` or `C`.  For example `C1:C3` would return `$A:$C` and `R[1]:R[2]` would return the relative reference of the two full rows directly below the referenced cell

Comment: Thanks Scott, I've plugged that in and then put the formula in a basic cell loop but am getting "application-defined or object-defined error". would you be able to assist as to why? I have just added the code to the quesiton

Comment: This is different, there was a typo in your original formula, there was an extra `)` in the formula.  Try the one I just posted.

Comment: Also I gave bad advice in my comment hence the repost in the answer.

Comment: That's perfect Scott, thanks so much for the help!! So would I be correct in saying when referencing a new sheet, R1C1 will automatically start at the beginning of the sheet?

Comment: also can only accept the answer in 2 mins but will be sure to do so! :)

Comment: Give me a second and I will edit the post to explain better.